# format phone number dupplicate himself while tapping

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

when i'm typing the phone number in my textfield the number duplicate him self everytime, like for example : i'm typing the number 5 in the keyboard, it will add 55 instead of 5, please find below my code

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == phoneUser
    {
        let newString = (textField.text! as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
        let components = newString.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet)

        let decimalString : String = components.joinWithSeparator("")
        let length = decimalString.characters.count
        let decimalStr = decimalString as NSString
        let hasLeadingOne = length > 0 && decimalStr.characterAtIndex(0) == (1 as unichar)

        if length == 0 || (length > 10 && !hasLeadingOne) || length > 11
        {
            let newLength = (textField.text! as NSString).length + (string as NSString).length - range.length as Int

            return (newLength > 10) ? false : true
        }
        var index = 0 as Int
        let formattedString = NSMutableString()

        if hasLeadingOne
        {
            formattedString.appendString("1 ")
            index += 1
        }
        if (length - index) > 3
        {
            let areaCode = decimalStr.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(index, 3))
            formattedString.appendFormat("(%@)", areaCode)
            index += 3
        }
        if length - index > 3
        {
            let prefix = decimalStr.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(index, 3))
            formattedString.appendFormat("%@-", prefix)
            index += 3
        }

        let remainder = decimalStr.substringFromIndex(index)
        formattedString.appendString(remainder)

        textField.text = formattedString as String
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //length of max characteres for uitextfield and lowercase
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Username.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.None
    if string.characters.count == 0 {
        return true
    }
    let currentText = textField.text ?? ""
    let prospectiveText = (currentText as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string.lowercaseString)
    if let _ = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSCharacterSet.uppercaseLetterCharacterSet()) {
        // Do not allow upper case letters
        return false
    }

    switch textField {
    case Name:
        return prospectiveText.doesNotContainCharactersIn("0123456789") &&
        prospectiveText.characters.count <= 34
    case website:
        return prospectiveText.characters.count <= 34
    case aboutUser:
        return prospectiveText.characters.count <= 64
    default:
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: i'm typing the number 5 in the keyboard, it will add 55 instead of 5 in my texfield

Comment: Where's the rest of your code? You must return `true` or `false`. I don't see you doing that. Show your real code, please.

Comment: I added the missing code, when I delete a number with the keyboard, it will delete two number in the same time lol

Comment: Any reason you seem to only want to support phone numbers from one country?

Comment: You must not return `true` and also set the text. You return `true`, or else you return `false` and also set the text.

Comment: no reason ! because I didn't find a good example for adding countries with some codes, do you have a good tutorial for that ? I will be happy to take it :)

Comment: @MamounMK Do a search. There are plenty of discussions and 3rd party libraries for formatting phone numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule for this delegate method is very simple: if you return `true` you must not *also* set the text field's text. If you do that, everything will happen twice.

Comment: Thanks ! simple and easy, If I want do that by country, where can find an example of code about that ? thank you